# Problem mocking hibernate's SessionFactory using Mockito

Tags: java, hibernate, mocking, mockito

Any idea why the following mocking code does not work?

```
org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);
org.hibernate.Session session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
```

The thenReturn statement does not compile.
"The method thenReturn(Session) in the type OngoingStubbing is not applicable for the arguments (Session)" 
But, why is it not applicable? I think I have the imports figured out correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the type actually returned by `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is `org.hibernate.classic.Session`, which is a sub-type of `org.hibernate.Session`. You'll need to change your mock to the correct type:

```
org.hibernate.classic.Session session = Mockito.mock(org.hibernate.classic.Session.class);
```